# my kivy apps don't run anymore on my Ubuntu computer after an Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, kivy

**(SOLVED)**

I used to have running kivy apps on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer. kivy did run very nicely.
Then I decided to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.
The upgrade process (online) went fine.

Unfortunately, since the upgrade all my kivy apps don't want to run anymore. They stop with this error :

```
##################################### snip
[INFO        ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO        ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[INFO        ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO        ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO        ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO        ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[CRITICAL    ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name bcm
##################################### snip
```

Note : kivy was installed via pip inside a virtualenv.

I decided to destroy my virtualenv and to recreate it and to reinstall things via pip install. Here is my pip list :

```
##################################### snip
appdirs (1.4.0)
buildozer (0.32)
colorama (0.3.7)
Cython (0.23)
docutils (0.13.1)
Jinja2 (2.8)
Kivy (1.9.1)
Kivy-Garden (0.1.4)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
packaging (16.8)
pexpect (4.2.1)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
ptyprocess (0.5.1)
pyparsing (2.1.10)
requests (2.13.0)
setuptools (34.0.2)
sh (1.12.9)
six (1.10.0)
virtualenv (15.1.0)
wheel (0.30.0a0)
##################################### snip
```

**Important to mention :**

I did follow the notes found on :
https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#dependencies-with-sdl2

**So what I did is :**

- I installed all the SDL2 libraries
- I installed Cython version 0.23
- I installed kivy with : pip install Kivy --no-cache-dir

Unfortunately, when I launch one kivy app it stops at the error above.

**I tried something else :**

I installed kivy via Ubuntu packages : same error!!!

**So my idea is :**

There is probably something (a library/some libraries) that prevents kivy apps to run, but what?

**To summarize :**

- a launch with kivy installed via pip install
- a launch with kivy installed with apt-get install

Both method end to the same error.

Whatever I do I always get this same error mentioned above.

Any help really appreciated!
Thanks

**PS : here is the full output of the launch. There is this line :**

```
x11 - ImportError: No module named window_x11
```

I don't know if it helps.

**The full output below :**

```
################################ snip
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/richard/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-01-26_1.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name bcm
  File "/home/richard/programmation/python/tests/kivy/kv_and_py/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/home/richard/programmation/python/tests/kivy/kv_and_py/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - RuntimeError: Could not create GL context: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  File "/home/richard/programmation/python/tests/kivy/kv_and_py/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/home/richard/programmation/python/tests/kivy/kv_and_py/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/home/richard/programmation/python/tests/kivy/kv_and_py/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/home/richard/programmation/python/tests/kivy/kv_and_py/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 237, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 140, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (/tmp/pip-build-DtbP_O/Kivy/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:2359)
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 55, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die (/tmp/pip-build-DtbP_O/Kivy/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1479)

x11 - ImportError: No module named window_x11
  File "/home/richard/programmation/python/tests/kivy/kv_and_py/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
################################ snip
```

**SOLVED**

Since the upgrade, the graphics system (OpenGL) was broken. So I installed the correct driver for my Nvidia card and now everything is working!

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4085) might help you.

Comment: There are no solutions given in that link : they talk about pygame or windows or python3.

Comment: Perhaps I found a path to my problems! I tried to launch an opengl game (foobillardplus) to test the graphics. And Bingo! I got the same error : "X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)". So the problem comes from my new Ubuntu 16.04 system. Any idea to get further?